# A problem regarding composition of functions and fixing two points in the complex plane.

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

Let $f : \Bbb C → \Bbb C$ be an isometry fixing the origin and such that $f(1) = e^{iθ}$. Let $g : \Bbb C → \Bbb C$ be another isometry given by $g(z) = e^{iθ}z$.

a). Show that $g^{−1} ◦ f$ fixes both $0$ and $1$.

b). Show that either $f(z) = e^{iθ}z$ or that $f(z) = e^{iθ} \bar z$

So far, I have found that $g^{−1}(z) = e^{-iθ}z$ which implies that $(g^{−1} ◦ f) (1) = 1$. So I know this fixes $1$. So now I need to show that $(g^{−1} ◦ f) (0) = 0$. But I don't know how to do that with the information provided without just making the assumption that $f(z) =e^{iθ}(z)$ or  $f(z) =e^{iθ}(\bar z)$.

So assuming that everything in part a) is true, since $(g^{−1} ◦ f) (1)= 1$ and $(g^{−1} ◦ f) (0) = 0$, $(g^{−1} ◦ f)(z) =e^{-iθ}f(z) $ In order for $e^{-iθ}f(1) = 1$ and $e^{-iθ}f(0) = 0$ to be true, $f(1)$ must equal $e^{iθ}(1)$ and then $f(0)$ can equal the product of anything and $0$. But since we have that $e^{iθ}(1) = 1$, it is also true that $e^{iθ}(0) = 0$. So we can say that $f(z) =e^{iθ}(z)$. But since $1$ and $0$ are fixed by $f$, it can also be that case that $f(z) =e^{iθ}(\bar z)$. I suppose the issue is showing that it can't be anything else aside from these two.

So, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $f(0)=g(0)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this function is an isometry, it follows that it is an isomorphism.  That's one way since isomorphisms have to preserve certain elements.

Incidentally it doesn't matter because you've already assumed that f fixes the origin.  So whatever f is, $f(0)=0$.

So ($g^{-1} * f$) (0) = $g^{-1}(0)$

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I glanced over the part that says fixes the origin. Thank you for point that out. It makes it so much easier.

Comment: No problem.  However, as I said, you didn't necessarily need to have it explicitly stated either.  By definition, any isomorphism of a field is going to preserve the identity elements under both operations.  This is a very important characteristic when you start studying automorphisms.

Comment: That is a good way to look at it but we haven't learned isomorphisms yet. However I will keep this in mind for solving these in the future. Thank You so much.